# Upload photo to Facebook and keep link Upload by AppName

Tags: ios, facebook, upload

I use following code to post photo to the wall

```
            [FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:img
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                               }];
```

It works fine. In iOS 5.1 there is link under photo that directs to itunes to download my app.
I like that.

But in iOS 6.1 there is link to iOS. It tells uploaded by iOS.

How do I replace it with my app name like in iOS 5.1 or add another link to my app?

I use FB iOS SDK 3.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use opengraph to do it. It's a fair bit of work to implement, but it does give you an even more prominent link and lots of other options.

I contacted someone at facebook to ask their advice about this and they sent me these links.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/overview/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/creating-open-graph-stories/

Comment: Thank You.  Will it require publish rights? These code shows nice native iOS dialog. Asks user to leave comment and publishes it. If I will use OpenGraph then I will have to ask for publish permissions instead that player will less likely give then just click upload near image as player will see what exactly would be published. Thank is definitely could solution if I would not be able to work with current dialog.